# why the AudioRecord instance cannot be restarted after a prior stop

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am developing an android voice recognition app, which makes use of Android's AudioRecord class, everything goes along well except this flaw. The recorder(an instance of AudioRecord) cannot be restarted again after a stop, and it led to a GC_CONCURRENT to jump in to claim garbage after which the program exited. I doubt there's some memory leak, but couldn't get my heads around it.

Below is my code:

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SphinxUtil.syncAssets;
import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.sphinxbase.setLogFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Config;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Decoder;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;


public class PocketSphinxAndroidDemo extends Activity {

    private class RecognitionTask
            extends AsyncTask<AudioRecord, Void, Hypothesis> {

        private final Decoder decoder;

        public RecognitionTask() {
            File root = null;

            try {
                root = syncAssets(getApplicationContext(), "models");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            File rootLog = new File(root.getParentFile(), "pocketsphinx.log");
            setLogFile(rootLog.getPath());

            Config config = Decoder.defaultConfig();

            config.setString("-lm",  new File(root, "lm/hub4.5000.DMP").getPath());
            config.setString("-hmm", new File(root, "hmm/hub4wsj_sc_8k").getPath());
            config.setString("-dict",new File(root, "lm/hub4.5000.dic").getPath());
            config.setString("-rawlogdir", root.getPath());

            config.setString("-rawlogdir", root.getPath());
            config.setFloat("-samprate", SAMPLE_RATE);
            config.setInt("-maxhmmpf", 10000);
            config.setBoolean("-backtrace", true);
            config.setBoolean("-bestpath", false);
            config.setBoolean("-remove_noise", false);

            decoder = new Decoder(config);
        }

        protected Hypothesis doInBackground(AudioRecord... recorder) {
            int nread;
            short[] buf = new short[1024];
            decoder.startUtt(null);


            while ((nread = recorder[0].read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0){
                decoder.processRaw(buf, nread, false, false);
            }
            decoder.endUtt();
            return decoder.hyp();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
            if (null != hypothesis)
                speechResult.append("\n" + hypothesis.getHypstr());
            else
                speechResult.append("\n<no speech>");
        }
    }

    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;
    private static final String TAG="PocketSphinxAndroidDemo";
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
    }

    private TextView speechResult;
    private AudioRecord recorder;
    private RecognitionTask recTask;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        speechResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SpeechResult);

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                                   SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                   AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 204800);
        recTask = new RecognitionTask();
    }

    public void onToggleRecognition(View view) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I in ToggleRecognition");
        if (!(view instanceof ToggleButton))
            return;

        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
            recorder.startRecording();
            recTask.execute(recorder);
        } else {
            recorder.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("OnDestroy");
        recorder.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to review your threads...

on Main, it looks like you do 'recorder.start' & 'recorder.stop'

However, you control the decoder in the background thread with 'decoder.start..' , 'decoder.end..'

IMO, you should be managing ALL control methods for BOTH recorder and encode/decode in the background thread not doing start/stop recorder from Main thread and start/stop decode in background without any means of communication/coordination between the threads.

It is a much more complicated app, it works, you may want to look at [AudioBoo](https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android) and at where it controls the recorder/encoder stuff i mention above ( all in background, all in same thread )

see audioboo classes '[FLACRecorder](https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/FLACRecorder.java)' and 'BooRecorder' and look close at 'start/stop' related methods in these 2 classes, and how they interact from their respective threads. It is quite different use of threads than what your code does.

**OR**

It is far less likely, IMO, but there may be some issues in the 'sphinx' library that you are loading that prevent it from being called a 2nd time without doing an explicit 'unload', 'reload' cycle. You could check the forums there in order to see whether there exist issues with calling in to the lib twice without unloading, reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that when you `stop()` your `AudioRecord` object, you should also call `release()` otherwise you won't be able to restart it.

This may not be your entire issue but will certainly be causing issues.